# Scatter plot for every pairs in a two column matrix

Tags: excel, matlab, xmgrace

I have a matrix which contains the atom numbers of the pairs of atoms which are in contact with each other. My matrix is like this:

```
column 1: atom number i;
column 2: atom number j
```

`i,j` runs from 1 to 800.

If there is a pair `i-j` in the matrix, place a dot corresponding to the position `(i,j)` of the matrix.
How do I plot such matrix?

**Example:**

```
A= [1,3; 3,8; 3,1; 6,2; 2,6; 1,2; 5,2; 8,3; 2,5; 2,1]
```

I want to Plot the matrix `A`, where X and Y-axis run from 1 to 8. Place a dot for every combination of `X` and `Y` which are present in `A`.

**I want a plot like this:**

[image: I want a plot like this.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this just a scatter plot?

If your `m x 2` matrix is saved in a text file then this is trivial. 
Here are the contents of an example data file "input.dat":

```
4 3
3 4
5 3
3 5
8 2
2 8
```

All you need to do is open the data file in xmgrace using `xmgrace input.dat`.
Now, initially it will be a line plot, but if you do 'Plot' > 'Set Appearance' and then with the only set already being selected you can set the 'Symbol Properties' 'Type:' to Diamond and 'Line Properties' 'Type:' to None you will already be on your way. Setting the symbol fill to solid red, tweaking the axis ranges and showing major tick grid lines will give a plot like the one you gave as an example.

[image]

You can save a parameters file and in future load the parameters at the beginning using

`xmgrace -param template.par input2.dat`.

But, having said all this, why not just plot it in matlab?